# Mongoose - saving objects in pre save hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `documents` that I want to create, but those documents contain `urls`, so the `document` structure looks like this:

```
const document = {
  name: 'some name',
  text: 'some text,
  file_type: 'file type',
  urls: [{
    path: 'some path',
    display_url: 'some path',
  }],
};
```

I have `DocumentSchema` and `URLSchema` created looking like this:

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  file_type: String,
  name: String,
  urls: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'URL' }],
});

const URLSchema = new Schema({
  path: String,
  display_url: String,
});
```

Now I want to create multiple documents so I pass an array of document objects to `Document.create`:

```
Document.create(documents, (err, documents) => {
   // ...
})
```

I want to create the URLs before the documents get saved, so I created a `pre save` hook:

```
Document.pre('save', true, function (next, done) {
  console.log('Saving doc', this);
  // probably URL.insertMany(this.urls) ???
});
```

**My problem**

`this` object doesn't contains those `urls`, but objects in the array of the `documents` passed to `Document.create` have `urls`.

What should I do to create the `URLs` before the `Document` is saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should plugin your `pre` middleware in `DocumentSchema`

```
  DocumentSchema.pre('save', function(next){
      URL.insertMany(this.urls, function(err, res){
          if(err) throw err;
          next();
      })
  });
```

example

```
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    path: String,
    urls: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'URL' }],
  });

  const URLSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    display_url: String,
    ref: Boolean,
  });

  const URL = mongoose.model('URL', URLSchema, 'urls');

  DocumentSchema.pre('save', function(next){
      URL.insertMany(this.urls, function(err, res){
          if(err) throw err;
          next();
      })
  });

  const Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema, 'documents');
```

sample insert

```
  var u1 = new URL({url : 'www.google.com'});
  var d1 = new Document({text: 'test text', urls : [u1]})
  var u2 = new URL({url : 'www.google.com'});
  var d2 = new Document({text: 'test text', urls : [u2]})  
  Document.create([d1, d2], function(err, docs){
      if(err) console.log(err)
      console.log(docs)
  })
```

Comment: But the case is that `this.urls` is always an empty array, but the `documents` passed to `Document.create` contain the `urls` attribute.

Comment: you can see in the object creation, document has the reference of url, while saving the document, the pre hook saves the urls, you can see in log

Comment: I want to be able to pass an array of `documents` to `Document.create`, not just one. If I'm passing a one object, I get `ValidationError: Document validation failed: urls: Cast to Array failed for value ...`

Comment: So I order to actually save multiple, I would have to map the `urls` in the `documents` object to `URL`s?

Comment: yes, you need to map urls to URL, see the edit it works for multiple inserts as well